_interopRequireDefault2 is not a function
Environment

Operating System: Darwin
Node Version:     v20.11.0
Nuxt Version:     3.14.159
CLI Version:      3.15.0
Nitro Version:    2.10.4
Package Manager:  npm@10.2.4
Builder:          -
User Config:      default
Runtime Modules:  @nuxt/image@1.8.1, vue-yandex-maps/nuxt, nuxt-swiper@1.2.2, @pinia/nuxt@0.5.5, nuxt-mongoose@1.0.6, @sidebase/nuxt-auth@0.9.4, @nuxt/test-utils/module@3.14.4, yandex-metrika-module-nuxt3@1.5.3, @nuxtjs/seo@2.0.0-rc.23, @nuxtjs/i18n@8.5.6
Build Modules:    -

Reproduction
my [...].ts file
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    secret: useRuntimeConfig().authSecret,
    pages: {
        error: '/auth/error',
        signOut: '/?isLogout=true',
    },
    providers: [CredentialsProvider.default({
        name: 'credentials',
        credentials: {},
        async authorize(credentials: {email: string, password: string}){
            const user = await UserSchema.findOne({email: credentials.email})
            if (!user) {
                throw createError({
                    statusCode: 401,
                    statusMessage: 'User is not found',
                })
            }
            const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password)
            if (!isPasswordValid) {
                throw createError({
                    statusCode: 401,
                    statusMessage: 'errorPasswordWrong',
                })
            }
            return {
                ...user.toObject(),
                password: ''
            }
        }
    })],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = {
                    _id: user._id,
                    email: user.email,
                }
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            const user = await UserSchema.findById(token.user._id)
            session.user = user
            return session
        },
    }
});

nuxt.config.ts
auth: {
    baseURL: `${process.env.NUXT_AUTH_ORIGIN}`,
    provider: {
        type: 'authjs',
        defaultProvider: 'credentials',
        addDefaultCallbackUrl: false,
    },
  },

Describe the bug
I have this an error
next-auth_react.js?v=ff837320:4048 Uncaught TypeError: _interopRequireDefault2 is not a function
at node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js (next-auth_react.js?v=ff837320:4048:24)
at __require (chunk-V4OQ3NZ2.js?v=ff837320:11:50)
at next-auth_react.js?v=ff837320:4628:16
Additional context
When I run my nuxt application via npm run dev, I have this problem. But in production building I don't have it.
Logs
No response
